# API Throttle in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I was seeing [this tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-2/episodes/2) about throttle in Laravel 5.2

It seems that throttle is just used for APIs, but why couldn't be used for other controller stuff, to avoid that people send 100 times the same form through Postman.

I tell that, because in the Kernel.php, now, middleware are clearly divided between web and apis: [Kernel.php:Laravel 5.2](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php)

Comment: Well yes, it's just a middleware and can therefore be appended to any route /controller regardless of whether that route is for an API or not. It merely limits how many times an IP address can hit a set of routes within a period of time. So it can be used to limit submission of a form, as you suggestion, 100 times.

Comment: but what I'm saying, is that it seems designed to be only used for APIs, and I don't understand this decision

Comment: Why do you say that? Although Laravel is used by a lot of its user base to create APIs so any decision that supports API development would make sense to be honest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply it to web pages as well. Judging from your comments, you're confused as to the new features of Middleware, primarily [Middleware Groups](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#middleware-groups).

5.2 brought along with it a way to group Middleware like you would with Route groups before. In 5.1 you would do something like:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware'=>'auth,custom_middleware,permission:edit_permissions'], function() {
    Route::post('permissions/{id}/store', ['uses'=>'PermissionController@store']);
});
```

That is still completely valid, but if you wanted to add another Route group with the same middleware, you had to either juggle organization so they were nested beneath a single Route group that applied those middleware or you had to copy paste the middleware, neither very desirable. With 5.2, all you have to is this:

```
Kernel.php

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'permissions_api' => [
         'auth', 
         'custom_middleware',
         'permission:edit_permissions',
     ]
];

routes.php

Route::group(['middleware' => ['permissions_api']], function () {
    Route::post('permissions/{id}/store', ['uses'=>'PermissionController@store']);
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['permissions_api']], function () {
    Route::post('permissions/{id}/update', ['uses'=>'PermissionController@update']);
});
```

So you can group those middleware and apply them in those groups. That's what the `api` and `web` you are seeing is. It's just the default Middleware groups provided by Laravel that you can modify however you want. `throttle` is available as Middleware where ever you may need it. The below are both perfectly valid

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['throttle:60,1']], function () {
    Route::post('permissions/{id}/update', ['uses'=>'PermissionController@update']);
});
```

or

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'permissions_api' => [
         'auth', 
         'custom_middleware',
         'permission:edit_permissions',
         'throttle:60,1'
     ] 
];
```

So `throttle` is just a middleware and can be applied just as any middleware is. It is defined in `Kernel.php` as `'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,` and the `60,1` are just middleware parameters, which were added in 5.1